# Devise mailer URLs not working in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have the following vanilla reset password mailer set up for Devise. This renders the reset password mail with correct URLs in development, but throws an error in production with
`undefined local variable or method 'controller' for #<ResetPasswordMailer:0x00000007248f68>`

It looks like the helpers are getting loaded fine, but the generated routes are having issues in production only.

Partial stack trace:

```
actionview (4.1.1) lib/action_view/routing_url_for.rb:99:in `_routes_context'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:372:in `block (2 levels) in define_mounted_helper'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:378:in `main_app'
devise (3.5.1) lib/devise/controllers/url_helpers.rb:63:in `_devise_route_context'
devise (3.5.1) lib/devise/controllers/url_helpers.rb:50:in `block (4 levels) in generate_helpers!'
app/mailers/reset_password_mailer.rb:7:in `reset_password_instructions'
```

Source files:

```
# app\mailers\reset_password_mailer.rb
class ResetPasswordMailer < Devise::Mailer
end

# app\views\devise\mailer\reset_password_instructions.html.erb
<p>Hello <%= @resource.email %>!</p>

<p>Someone has requested a link to change your password. You can do this through the link below.</p>

<p><%= link_to 'Change my password', edit_password_url(@resource, reset_password_token: @token) %></p>

<p>If you didn't request this, please ignore this email.</p>
<p>Your password won't change until you access the link above and create a new one.</p>
```

Update:

This is caused by the `config.eager_load = true` setting in `production.rb`. Changing it to `false` does not seem like an optimal solution though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `<%= link_to 'Change my password', spree.edit_password_url(@resource, reset_password_token: @token) %>`

```
# app\views\devise\mailer\reset_password_instructions.html.erb
<p>Hello <%= @resource.email %>!</p>

<p>Someone has requested a link to change your password. You can do this through the link below.</p>

<p><%= link_to 'Change my password', spree.edit_password_url(@resource, reset_password_token: @token) %></p>

<p>If you didn't request this, please ignore this email.</p>
<p>Your password won't change until you access the link above and create a new one.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue was caused by `config.eager_load = true` on Rails 4.1.2. It works fine after upgrading to Rails 4.2.0.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I recently had the same issue on a Rails 7 application. The app had been working correctly for several months and suddently it started throwing this error.

I solved it adding the following method to the mailer class:

```
class DeviseMailer < Devise::Mailer
  layout 'mailer'

  # Avoid no method error in production (eager_load = true) 
  def controller
    nil
  end
end
```